# How to fix "You have an error in your SQL syntax" JPA Persistence

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

In my JPA entity I have a formula to calculate if data is is used in another table. (I'm using a MySQL database)

I tried the same query directly in the database with MySQL workbench and it works.

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CASE_TYPE")
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CaseType {
  @Formula("SELECT * FROM case_for_map c WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM case_type ct WHERE ct.id = c.case_type_id)")
  private Boolean usedInMap;
}
```

Actualy I got

```java
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM case_for_map c WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM case_type ct WHERE ' at line 1
```

Any idea on how to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, not enough parentheses.

```java
public class CaseType {
  @Formula("(SELECT * FROM case_for_map c WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM case_type ct WHERE ct.id = c.case_type_id))")
  private Boolean usedInMap;
}
```

Comment: When I try this I got : java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Select in formula must return only one column. Like this `(SELECT 0 FROM case_for_map c WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM case_type ct WHERE ct.id = c.case_type_id))`